System of two polynomial equations in two unknowns
Solve for positive reals $(x,y)$ the two equations:
$$
(17 y^2 - 13 x^2) (y-x) = 55\\
3 y^2 - x^2 = 11
$$
One can first check the possible number of solutions.  The second equation requires $y \ge \sqrt{11/3}$. Letting $a = x-y$ one gets
that
$$
a = -y + \sqrt{3y^2-11}\\
a = \frac{5}{2y^2 - 13}
$$
Whereas the first equation for $a$ is rising with $y$ for  $y \ge \sqrt{11/3}$, the second has two branches which are both falling with $y$, so there can be at most two real solutions. Checking plots and graphical solutions shows that the solutions are $(x,y) = (1,2)$ and   $(x,y) = (4,3)$.
However, what is asked here is to derive these solutions from the two original  equations.  "Simply" replacing one into the other gives a sixth order polynomial equation where, in hindsight, two product factors such as  $(y-2)(y-3)$ can be split off by polynomial division, but that only works if the solutions are known and should not be done. Any clever way to do this, for example,  with substitutions or a-priori known factorizations?

If you suspect there are integer solutions, you might note that $55$ doesn't have a lot of integer divisors.

@RobertIsrael The task does not ask for integer solutions.

@Andreas You concluded that there would be at most two real solutions. Wondering if those solutions might be integer is a totally legitimate attempt (which works in this case!).

True, but problems that people make up often do have integer solutions.

Thanks guys. Again, the point is exactly not to guess solutions and then prove that they match, as I laid out in the question.  If you want to focus on integer solutions then prove first of all that the equations indeed do have only integer solutions.

The sixth order equation on $a$ is $$a^6-30a^4+4a^2+25-20a^3+20a=0,$$for which $a^2=1$ is an obvious pair of solutions.

@AnneBauval Yes, that's the equation. "Obvious" is disputable: if you do not rely on guessing (and luckily $a = \pm 1$ would be a good first try for guessing), then please provide a principled way for arriving at a solution.

Imo, $1-30+4+25=1-1=0$ is obvious, so no such prior "guess" as $a=\pm1$ is needed.

@AnneBauval Fine. But all of this misses the point which I clearly laid out in the question. All of you rely on integers, easy guesses, sumcheck methods etc. for simple solutions.  If any solution would be $12/29$, say (and maybe I should rewrite the question that way), then this would never be obvious. Again: the question asks for principled methods, like substitutions or a-priori known factorizations, for approaching the pair of equations.

Again: I don't rely on integers nor any guess. The solution of your problem (not any more complicated one) becomes really obvious thanks to this rewriting. I honestly doubt you can hope for better. If you like it, a "principle method" could be: $a=\pm\sqrt t$ is a solution of $P(a^2)+aQ(a^2)=0$ as soon as $(\gcd(P,Q))(t)=0$.

This does not work Maybe you can fix it:. We could write $3 y^2 - x^2 = 11$ as:
$-3(x+y)(y-x)=11-2 x^2 \tag{A}$.
1st equation is:
$(17 y^2 - 13 x^2) (y-x) = 55 \tag{B}$.
Comparing R.H.S in (A),(B) leads to $x=\sqrt{22}i,:x=-\sqrt{22}i$

Let's mark the two equations as $E_1: (17y^2 - 13x^2)(y - x) = 55$ and $E_2: 3y^2 - x^2 = 11$.
From $E_2$: $y^2 = \frac{x^2 + 11}{3}$
Notice that $55 = 5 * 11$, and therefore from $E_1$ and $E_2$: $(17y^2 - 13x^2)(y - x) = 55 = 5 * 11 \stackrel{11 = 3y^2 - x^2}{=} 5 * (3y^2 - x^2) = 15y^2 - 5x^2$
Substituting $y^2 = \frac{x^2 + 11}{3}$:
$$
\left(17 * \frac{x^2 + 11}{3} - 13x^2 \right)(y - x) = 15 * \frac{x^2 + 11}{3} - 5x^2 \\ 
\Rightarrow \left(-\frac{22}{3}x^2 + \frac{187}{3}\right)(y - x) = 55 \\ \Rightarrow 
(-22x^2 + 187)(y - x) = 165 \\ \Rightarrow 
y - x = \frac{165}{-22x^2 + 187} \rightarrow y = \frac{165}{-22x^2 + 187} + x
$$
Squaring both sides:
$$
y^2 = \frac{x^2 + 11}{3} = \frac{27225}{(187 - 22x^2)^2} + x^2 + \frac{330x}{187 - 22x^2}
\\ 
$$
We can check that if $x^2 = \frac{187}{22}$ then $x$ wouldn't be a solution to the problem. Therefore, we can muptiply both sides with $3(187-22x^2)^2$.
$$
484x^6 - 2904x^4 - 55539x^2 + 384659 = 1452 x^6 - 24684x^4 - 21780x^3 + 104907x^2 + 185130x + 81675
$$
However, from here, I don't think we can have so much "clever solution" for this. That is because the last equation has some really complicated solutions. But your solution of $x = 1$ and $x = 4$ does make the list, along with a value of $x \approx 3.1307$, and since $y$ is positive we can use the relation $y = \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + 11}{3}}$ to get $y$s from $x$s respectively.
Calculations are supported by Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha =)))

oh, I didn't pay attention to it much. I was mostly focusing on $x$, which indeed has no condition (other than $x > 0$)
